# Why is the SVG stroke not updating despite applied styles being visible in the inspected element?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

I have a downloaded SVG with a default black stroke. In my React app with Tailwind CSS, I'm attempting to change the stroke color to white. Despite inspecting the element and verifying that the style is applied, the color isn't updating on the page. Can anyone help me understand why the stroke color change is not being reflected?

[image]

CODE:

```
const SVG = () => {
  return <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    height="20"
    viewBox="0 -960 960 960"
    width="20"
    className="stroke-white"
   >
   <path d="M261-120q-24.75 0-42.375-17.625T201-180v-570h-41v-60h188v- 
    30h264v30h188v60h- 41v570q0 24-18 42t-42 18H261Zm438-630H261v570h438v-570ZM367- 
    266h60v-399h-60v399Zm1660h60v-399h-60v399ZM261-750v570-570Z" 
   />
  </svg>
}
export default SVG
```

Comment: The SVG as-is has its visible areas [colored by `fill`, not `stroke`](https://play.tailwindcss.com/vJ8AiYYgV8). However, it does not seem like you have provided the same SVG that would render like in your image. Consider providing the real SVG code.